# Partitioning and installing on non formatted drive

Tags: format, opensuse, hard-drive

I have ubuntu installed on a 500 GB drive that is not formatted in any way, not ntfs, ext, or fat. I have been using this for some time and no errors have occurred. Would it be safe to install opensuse on the same drive? I am already multibooting with other windows and linux installs on other drives.
EDIT: Sorry, I guess it is formatted ext 4 accorrding to the below. Every other drive manager I have used has always returned nothing.
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1     ext4   469015024  51725960 393464424  12% /
none      devtmpfs     2024156       408   2023748   1% /dev
none         tmpfs     2028672       608   2028064   1% /dev/shm
none         tmpfs     2028672       224   2028448   1% /var/run
none         tmpfs     2028672         0   2028672   0% /var/lock
none         tmpfs     2028672         0   2028672   0% /lib/init/rw

Comment: The question is nonsense. You cannot install Ubuntu on a non-formatted drive. Try `df -T` from a terminal to see what filesystem you're actually using on the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install ubuntu on nothing. there has to be some sort of formating going on, be it ext2, ext3, ext4, xfs, reiserfs or whatever you can come up with. as long as you have kernel support for that particular file system on your computer and it has reasonable file permission and owner support you can install linux on it. it's just a matter of *which* file system.

Last time I checked ubuntu does not boot from raw file system. You can boot linux (the kernel) off a disk technically without a file system (dd if=vmlinuz of=/dev/fd0 etc..) and then use rdev to set the root fs but i doubt you would ask such a question if you knew all these...

to answer your question - most likely ubuntu had partitioned your harddrive without you knowing (or you may have forgotten, ubuntu had a nice installer, at least for me coming from using slackware and debian from early versions....) you need to resize the partition if you don't want to destroy the partitions.